# oracle SQL Developer shows null for number data type while Length function says ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table with a single number data type column and which SQL developer is (possibly incorrectly) displaying null values for, trying to pinpoint the issue by executing the following SQL:

`select length(myNumberColumn) from myTable`

returns

> ORA-01722: invalid number

`Trim()` also throws the same error. It seems some of the data may be bad, but my table has thousands of rows, how to identify the bad records? And seriously SQL Developer, is it null or an invalid number?  Is there a way to get SQL Developer to show the real values instead of null?

Comment: I don't see how `length()` can return that error.

Comment: Sounds like it could be [corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51365584/266304). What does `dump()` show for that value?

Comment: Interesting, hadn't seen dump() before.  The bad records came back with: Typ=2 Len=8: 255,248,0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: I had a simular problem (posted by Alex Poole) some days before using IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 what version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The problematic value was indeed appearing as (null) in SQL Developer, but exporting the data to csv and viewing in Excel showed the real value of the record and it was very large.... 1.10905886754731E+130   (basically infinity).  Ideally SQL developer wouldn't show a (null) for those type of records.

Comment: Exporting to CSV and importing into Excel both potentially change the value. `dump(myNumberColumn)` would be more reliable.

Comment: You are asking SQL Developer the impossible. The value is invalid to begin with. How **should** SQL Developer show such values? Ideally Oracle Database should not allow invalid values to be stored. It does - there are many ways to store invalid values, and the fault is with the database product, not with the front-end (SQL Developer).

Comment: [According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51364254/266304), SQL Navigator (not a client I've ever used!) shows 'error'. It doesn't seem unreasonable to think SQL Developer could show `(ERROR)` or `(INVALID)` or similar. One for Jeff...